# Excel VBA code for specific input which has combination of alphanumeric characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I actually want to remove any number of occurrences of single number, combination of numbers and combination of alphanumeric. I want a VBA code in excel help for the following data. Input is "Android Browser hsu601 0 1234" ouput should be "Android Browser". Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably there is more than one way to do this. You need to provide more/better data to find a pattern. With only one source data-set I see no chance to come to any solution. Please read [ask]

Comment: I actually want to remove any number of occurrences of single number, combination of numbers and combination of alphanumeric. Please help thanks

Comment: How could you do this? How can a computer distinguish between data you want to keep and you don't want to keep? I think that is the wrong approach. You will have to think about another strategy. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You will need to show the code you already have.

Comment: =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F:F,"."," "),"/"," "),"-","")) is the code used by me to simplify the data. As I am new to Excel I asked the further code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saif, the code I gave you yesterday would do exactly what you describe in **this** question.

```
Function strip_non_alpha_words(sentence As String) As String
Dim wrd_to_check As String
Dim wrd As Variant
For Each wrd In Split(sentence, " ")
    wrd_to_check = wrd
    If wrd_to_check = alpha_only(wrd_to_check) Then
        strip_non_alpha_words = strip_non_alpha_words & wrd_to_check & " "
    End If
Next
strip_non_alpha_words = Trim(strip_non_alpha_words)
End Function

Function alpha_only(mixedStr As String) As String
Dim ltr As Long, ascii_code As Long
For ltr = 1 To Len(mixedStr)
    ascii_code = Asc(UCase(Mid(mixedStr, ltr, 1)))
    If (ascii_code > 64 And ascii_code <= 90) Or (ascii_code >= 40 And ascii_code <= 41) Then
        alpha_only = alpha_only & Mid(mixedStr, ltr, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

You can use this in a formula (UDF) like so:

```
=strip_non_alpha_words(A1)
```

Using this in conjunction with your `TRIM` and multiple `SUBSTITUTE` formula would probably help, but you're still going to have a problem if you have something like `Application v1.3.B` as the `B` will still come through.

Comment: CLR I got Compile error for "wrd" variable stating variable not defined. After that I declared wrd As String, again I got compile error stating For each control variable must be Variant or Object. How do I rectify this error?

Comment: Declare it as a Variant instead of String?

Comment: Thanks. Its working

Comment: CLR I would like to trouble you for last time. Please modify the code, for input Opera (unknown version) the output generated is Opera where as I want ouput as Opera (unknown version). Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answer. I'm just adding `(` and `)` as acceptable characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot CLR.

Comment: CLR did you try that?

Comment: Can you please explain why you have used UCase function in "ascii_code = Asc(UCase(Mid(mixedStr, ltr, 1)))" line ?

Comment: I used the `Ucase` function to force all letters to upper case in the examination. The Ascii code for `A` is 65, but for `a` is 97. My test checks that the Ascii code is between 65 and 90 so unless I do this it would consider `a` as unacceptable. Alternatively, I could've not used `UCase` and instead check that the Ascii code is between 65 and 90 OR 97 and 122.

Comment: I had only that doubt in the code. Kindly provide me the code for inputs with ( ) as you had told earlier. Thanks

Comment: `(` is 40, `)` is 41